# Xamarin Forms ListView RecycleElement ForceUpdateSize not resize

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem in ListView, I have a cell that when the user clicks more information appears and when it clicks it disappears again.

Only that does not work when I do `ForceUpdateSize`, it does not appear.
I also set the `Height` but it does not work too.

Now if I put the `ListView` as `ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement`, it works. Already in `ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement` mode does not work.

Anyone know any solution?

Comment: It would usually be prudent to show us some of your existing code displaying how your currently trying to tackle the situation. It'll make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sounds like `ListView.HasUnevenRows` is not set to `true`? If it already is, what platform do you see this on?

Comment: The code is very simple a listview and a viewcell with a button that when clicking appears another item in the stacklayout that is in that viewcell.
HasUnevenRows = true